# Raspberry Pi 3 WiFi, Flight Radar24 -

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I've been trying for two days, have not been able to get my WiFi to work on Raspberry Pi 3

I've tried the Jessie Lite build from FR24, and even the full download from Raspberry site.

wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="-----"
psk="------"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
group=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

interfaces:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:4b:d5:3d
          inet addr:192.168.1.74  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:36c9:c70:e7a9:fcae:b690:40a6/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::66b9:e804:a95e:8576/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:837 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:53193 (51.9 KiB)  TX bytes:50627 (49.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13776 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13776 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:1145608 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1145608 (1.0 MiB)
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifup wlan0

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifdown wlan0

```
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured
```

completely confused, please help.
Thanks,
Brian.

Hi Joe,, the Flight Radar 24 dist is built on Raspbian Jessie light
here is the lsmod

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   10340  2
hci_uart               17943  1
btbcm                   5929  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             326105  22 bnep,btbcm,hci_uart
cfg80211              427855  0
rfkill                 16037  3 cfg80211,bluetooth
ir_xmp_decoder          2903  0
ir_lirc_codec           4863  0
lirc_dev                8310  1 ir_lirc_codec
ir_mce_kbd_decoder      3921  0
ir_sharp_decoder        2177  0
ir_sanyo_decoder        2433  0
ir_sony_decoder         2175  0
ir_jvc_decoder          2173  0
ir_rc6_decoder          2813  0
ir_rc5_decoder          2493  0
ir_nec_decoder          2621  0
r820t                  16592  0
rtl2832                11329  0
i2c_mux                 2457  1 rtl2832
dvb_usb_v2             13297  0
dvb_core               81104  2 rtl2832,dvb_usb_v2
rc_core                16468  12 ir_sharp_decoder,ir_xmp_decoder,lirc_dev,ir_lirc_codec,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,dvb_usb_v2,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_sanyo_decoder
joydev                  9024  0
snd_bcm2835            20511  0
snd_pcm                75698  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              19160  1 snd_pcm
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0
snd                    51844  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
spi_bcm2835             7286  0
bcm2835_gpiomem         3040  0
evdev                  11396  3
hid_logitech           20832  0
ff_memless              4750  1 hid_logitech
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
ipv6                  347530  32
```

and the lsusb:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c06a Logitech, Inc. USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: fr24? do you have an actual raspbian image? check the output of lsusb, lsmod and ifconfig -a

Comment: If you are going to fill your config files with rubbish you can't expect it to work. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your WiFi adapter's driver didn't load. This is frequently due to missing firmware. You may want to check your `/lib/firmware/brcm` folder: if it's missing or empty, try putting [these files](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/tree/master/brcm80211/brcm) there and reboot. You might also try to load the driver manually:

```
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

If that won't help, check `dmesg` output for clues (e.g. use `grep` to search for keywords like "wlan", "mac", "firmware", "error"). Those messages are often clear enough to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/ or just these pictures.

Click on this button in the upper right corner.

[image]

Select your network.

[image]

Enter the correct passphrase.

[image]

After some seconds you're done. On the next boot you will be connected automatically.

[image]

Also check what changes were made to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

**Without a GUI, it works like this:**

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to make the `wlan0` entry look like this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Shutdown `wlan0` and scan for APs:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo iwlist scan
...
      Cell 02 - Address: F0:D1:A9:FF:FF:FF
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"MOB 4"
...
```

Add the AP to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={
    ssid="MOB 4"
    psk="not my real psk"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Start `wpa_supplicant`:

```
sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: hello ott, this version of raspbian (jessie lite) doesn't have a gui

Comment: @BrianTucker I've edited my answer to include a non-GUI solution.

Comment: thanks ott, checked the changes got the following
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifdown lan0
ifdown: interface lan0 not configured
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

I'm beginning to wonder if I don't have a bad Pi3, this is from Vilros - anyone know of any diagnostics I could run?

Comment: @BrianTucker What do you get from `ifconfig wlan0` and `iwconfig wlan0` (maybe needs `sudo`)?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:/sbin $ sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

pi@raspberrypi:/sbin $ sudo iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     No such device

Comment: @BrianTucker Make at least the change  in `/etc/network/interfaces`, then make a shutdown, remove the USB power and wait some minutes before powering up again.

Comment: FOLKS,  it appears that my RPI3 was bad, I ordered a new one...and it works, so I'll send the old one back to Amazon.  Thank you for all the help -I learned a lot!